# QGIS: can't use the v.clean tool, and there is no v.clean.advanced tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I searched for clean in the QGIS toolbar, there is only `v.clean` tool but no `v.clean.advanced` tool, and the GRASS plug-in is installed. It fails when using `v.clean` tool

[image: plugin manager with search for grass]
[image: processing toolbox with search for clean]

---

Question:

- no v.clean.advanced tool
- using v.clean tool failed
- log message is here:

```
QGIS version: 3.28.4-Firenze
QGIS code revision: fd0fb72ab3
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.6.2
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
Algorithm started at: 2023-06-05T13:13:24
Algorithm 'v.clean' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-b' : False, '-c' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'error' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'input' : 'D:/可用城市/新一线城市/苏州市/姑苏区/姑苏区_百度建筑.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'threshold' : '0.01', 'tool' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 'type' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] }

g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_llHnxT/0f8e10529598485a96884b65ad97b125/crs.prj"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="D:\可用城市\新一线城市\苏州市\姑苏区\姑苏区_百度建筑.shp" output="vector_647d6ef4eacde2" --overwrite -o
g.region n=31.3775526 s=31.2620604 e=120.65064722 w=120.52608541
v.clean input=vector_647d6ef4eacde2 type="point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel" tool="break,snap,rmdangle,chdangle,rmbridge,chbridge,rmdupl,rmdac,bpol,prune,rmarea,rmline,rmsa" threshold="0.01" output=output81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3 error=error81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\8545929ebb4849f48b31538ba672d7fb\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="error81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\a679516a328243b18373653c3dc83b23\error.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
警告：Windows 不支持当前锁定地图集
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\user\Documents>chcp 936 1>NUL
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_llHnxT/0f8e10529598485a96884b65ad97b125/crs.prj"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
Starting GRASS GIS...
警告：Windows 不支持当前锁定地图集
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\user\Documents>chcp 936 1>NUL
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\8545929ebb4849f48b31538ba672d7fb\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
错误：Vector map <output81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3> not found
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="error81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\a679516a328243b18373653c3dc83b23\error.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
错误：Vector map <error81ab74ee0dfa4992b2d73692fa9438d3> not found
C:\Users\user\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_llHnxT\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
请按任意键继续. . .
dbmi: Protocol error
错误：无法打开数据库 <$GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db>
Execution completed in 17.20 seconds
Results:
{'error': 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_llHnxT\\a679516a328243b18373653c3dc83b23\\error.gpkg',
'output': 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_llHnxT\\8545929ebb4849f48b31538ba672d7fb\\output.gpkg'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_llHnxT/8545929ebb4849f48b31538ba672d7fb/output.gpkg
• C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_llHnxT/a679516a328243b18373653c3dc83b23/error.gpkg
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are expecting a "v.clean.advanced" tool?